# Why is Connection closed unexpectedly in WCF and ASP.NET web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, linq, wcf

This is the code that I am using in Asp.net web application. It is consuming a WCF service where there is a function receiveMsg( ).

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();

            //assigning the input values to the variables   


          **(This is Problem )** ArrayList messages =  new ArrayList(client.receiveMsg(ReceiverId_R.Text));

           receiveMsg_div.InnerHtml = "";
            foreach(var messg in messages)
            {
                //receiveMsg_div.InnerHtml += "<p>" + messg.sender_id + "send message" + messg.message + "</p>";
                receiveMsg_div.InnerHtml += "<p>" + messg + "send message"+ "</p>";
            }
        }
```

Problem is in line -

```
ArrayList messages =  new ArrayList(client.receiveMsg(ReceiverId_R.Text));
```

receiveMsg( ) looks like -

```
public ArrayList receiveMsg(String receiverId)
        {
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\abhinav\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WcfService1\WcfService1\Messages.xml");
            //XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"~/App_Data/Messages.xml");
            ArrayList messages = new ArrayList();

            var elements = from item in xdoc.Descendants("Messages").Descendants("Message")
                           where item.Element("ReceiverId").Value == receiverId
                           select new{ msgtxt = item.Element("MessageText").Value, sendid = item.Element("SenderId").Value };
            foreach (var element in elements)
            {
                Message msg = new Message();
                msg.sender_Id = element.sendid;
                msg.message = element.msgtxt;
                messages.Add(msg);
            }
            return messages;
        }
```

What am I doing Wrong ? Is it Linq or WCF Settings etc. ?

Edited -

This I have added in IService.cs -

```
[DataContract]
    public class Message
    {
        [DataMember]
        public String sender_Id{get; set;}
        [DataMember]
        public String message { get; set; }
    }
```

So what exactly I want to do is -

An XML file have lots of messages. I want to retrieve all messages and sender Id that correspond to receiver id. For that I have created a Message class with sender Id and message as members. I want to create an Array List of Message Class Objects and return that to client.

Stack Trace -

```
Communication ExceptionSystem.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at wcf_web_app.ServiceReference1.IService1.receiveMsg(String receiverId)
   at wcf_web_app.ServiceReference1.Service1Client.receiveMsg(String receiverId) in C:\Users\abhinav\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\wcf_web_app\wcf_web_app\Service References\ServiceReference1\Reference.cs:line 136
   at wcf_web_app._Default.Button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\abhinav\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\wcf_web_app\wcf_web_app\Default.aspx.cs:line 43
```

I feel there is some problem related to making ArrayList of Message Class Objects and returning it. Anything ?

Comment: How about you start by adding some basic error handling in your code and see what you can find out.

Comment: Actually I know the problem and the problem is in the line I stated above. Object is returned from WCF but is not being casted to ArrayList and thats where I dont know what to do.

Comment: Why would you cast the result of receiveMsg to ArrayList if it already is an ArrayList? So that is not the problem. The problem may be that the result is an empty list (as I assume you do not get an exception). The error is not in the line but in receiveMsg. Perhaps receiverId doesn't result in a match (case-sensitive?). As a sidenote, you shouldn't save a result to disk and then load it again.

Comment: In wcf in console i have logged the result and receiveMsg works fine it gives the desired output.

Comment: If receiveMsg works fine, then what's the problem? It already is an ArrayList so that can't be a problem. If you do get an exception, then add it to the question. Also, if recieveMsg isn't relevant then remove it and what has the title to do with the question? Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry I assumed its implicit. I have made edits. Please have a look .